# iOS app crashes on backgrounding and quickly relaunching, no crash log

Tags: objective-c, ios, background, crash

This is a strange issue because I have set my app to not run in the background. So when I launch the app, then hit the home button and then relaunch the app within a second by tapping the app icon, it crashes. I strange issue is that the crash is not logged and not visible in XCode device logs. Also, If I wait more than a second before relaunching, the app relaunches just fine.

I realize this is not a coding question but I would like to understand from other iOS developers if they have run into this issue at all, and if so, is there a remedy?

Comment: Apple likes to take care of background apps by itself. Please explain why you would like the app not to run in the background. And maybe where is another way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Issue might be some objects are getting released i.e. in simple words you need to maintain objects properly which I guess you are not maintaining.

For solving this issue, you can use instruments like allocation and check all objects allocations.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: as I mentioned, XCode is not registering this as a crash, and I don't think it is a crash. I suspect it is iOS shutting down the original instance of the app while backgrounding, and if the app is relaunched too soon, it kills the relaunched app as well. Like I said, if I wait 2 seconds before relaunching, everything is fine. I would like to hear from someone who has experienced this issues themselves.

Comment: yes, i have experienced this issue earlier and by maintaing objects reference count properly, issue got resolved.

Comment: I am using ARC and maintaining reference counts. The answer is too vague and not helpful. Anyone else have any insights?